# Return result from groovy readline

Tags: groovy

I need to read an Nth line from my text file and then assign that line to a string. I already have N, which I get with a loop. This needs to be for groovy:

**pseudo code**

```
Def temp = readline(Linenumber);
```

Comment: what's a "line number". You need to read text from a line identified by a number, or each line contains a number and you want to read it?

Comment: I'm confused; readline already returns a line as a string.

Comment: A line number is what line you are reading.  For instance I have a text file with 200 lines.  I need to return line number 159 which says "Hey how are you".  There for my string wiil be "hey how are you"

Comment: @Justin Then just readlines *n* times, and return the value of the *n*th read. If you're doing it a "lot", then you might want to consider reading the file in to a collection of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy adds the `readLines()` method to the `java.io.File` object which returns a `List` of the file's contents, one line per list entry.  So:

```
def lines = new File("myFile.txt").readLines()
def myLine = lines[N-1]
```

Comment: This worked for me, but the line is to long for what I need.  Now that I have the line can I return the last few characters?  From a specific position over would be ideal.  For instance if the line was "Hey how are you" and I wanted to return from the end of how.  The new string would be "are you"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to read the entire file into memory, you can do something like:

```
String readLineN( File f, int lineNo ) {
  f.withReader { r ->
    ret = ''
    lineNo.times {
      ret = r.readLine()
    }
    ret
  }
}

readLineN( new File( 'path.to.file' ), 11 )
```

Which will return the 11th line in the file (or `null` if the file has less than 11 lines)